# How to print translatable values in twig ( doctrine extension)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I am using [translatable](http://blog.lazycloud.net/en/symfony2-doctrineextentions-translatable/)

It can handle the data directly depending on the current locale setting.

However I want to access each data sometimes with ignoring locale setting.

in contoroller.

I can access each data like this.

```
    $transRepo = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation');
    $repo = $transRepo->findTranslations($myEntity);
    var_dump($repo['en']['comment']);
```

Then, is there any way to fetch each language data in twig??

```
{{comment}} // it shows the comment depending on the locale setting.

{{comment | trancelate(en)}} // I want to ignore the locale setting like this.
```

Comment: Are you using "Personal translations" or everything is wrapped up in a single entity?

Comment: I am not sure what the Personal translations means though, I think everything is wrapped in a single entity. I didn't make another entity for my data. There are two tables in my database though, 'myEntity', 'ext_translations'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about passing the translations to your Twig template since you need to show them:

```
$translations = $repository->findTranslations($article);
```

And then in your Twig template you could do something like:

```
{{ translations.en.comment }}
{{ translations.de.comment }}
{{ translations.fr.comment }}
```

The [official documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) might help.

Comment: For now , it can slove the problem.